# How to draw a precise angle with pen tool in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path, drawing, pen-tool

Is it possible to draw a precise angle with the pen tool in Adobe Photoshop CS6?

By using Shift key it is easy to draw 45° or 90° but I need for example 37.45°.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be far easier to draw in Illustrator and then copy paste into Photoshop. More on this later.

#### How to do this in Photoshop

Unfortunately theres no direct way of doing this in Photoshop. Don't let that discourage you it is still possible to this. We just need to fish slightly further.

1. Draw a line on horizontal or vertical.
2. Select the line.
3. Enter free transform for the path and type in a angle in the top toolbar.

   - **Important**: Make sure you draw a closed path or the transform tool wont work. Don't worry you  can delete the extra segment later. Or use line tool.
4. Done.

- Tip: you can move the rotation handle for precise work

[image: image capture]

**Image 1**: How to do this in PS.

#### Illustrator

Now in illustrator this is very straightforward:

1. enable the line tool.
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd> click on the point where you want the line to start
3. Type in line lenth and direction
4. Done, now copy paste the path to Photoshop.

#### Could this be done better.

Yes, we could make a script that does more or less what illustrator does. I dont have time right now but maybe somebody else does.

Answer (score 4):

You may consider, if no real solution arrives, using "Rotate Canvas" option.

1. Draw one side
2. Rotate the image (not the canvas as I originally wrote by mistake) by the desired angle, Image/Image Rotation/Arbitrary
3. Draw the other side of the angle
4. Rotate the image back by the same amount

This is awkward, I know, but that's the only thing I can think of.

UPDATE

It was in front of me all along! The simplest and totally non destructive way of working at any angle on any PS document is to use the "Rotate View" command, the shortcut being the letter R. Once in this view, the "view" can be rotated at precise angles by entering numeric values, or rotated freehand by click-and-drag. Since only the view is rotated, there is no image degradation at all. This should alleviate the worry that "image rotation" may degrade quality.

I wanted to add this to close the loop and present a very effective way of working on any image at any angle we want for various reasons. For the rotate view to work you may need to have graphic acceleration enabled in preferences.

Try it!

Comment: Unfortunately the constrain directions atleast on my rotate with the canvas :( So if you need to be precise its not really doing it. You can still do this, with precision, its much more convoluted though.

Comment: I meant to say, "Image Rotate" which allows "Arbitrary" rotation. I will also correct in the answer.

Comment: Ah yes that works +1. But it is destructive for the data. Instead, you could circumvent this by drawing in another document and copy paste over, in which case you could also dispense of one rotation.

Comment: It is "destructive" in the way it expands the canvas which can be trimmed after the work is done. But, doing it in another document and transferring to the original is a good idea.

Comment: Here is a demo image [showing the degradation](http://i.imgur.com/TBzjCEZ.png), I've rotated back and forth by 23,47 degrees. So definitely destructive unless all your data is in a smart object in which case the matrix concatenations cancel out.

Comment: Yes, it looks destructive. Ignore the suggestion.

Comment: @joojaa Have you done the same test with the free transform + rotation? It's also destructive in the exact same exact way... Your suggestion is alright ACEkin, it's weird degrees that creates this distortion and anyway, the question is about using the pen tool, which I guess makes this a non-issue from the start.

Comment: @go-junta offcourse but you can limit the free transform to individual layers. Rotating the entire arwork spills this problem everywhere.

Comment: @joojaa I think we both agree that the example is about one shape, and could even be on an empty canvas. "Rotate image" could be used too I guess. Point is, that distortion is present with both techniques, just to add precision about this specific point!

Comment: @go-junta sure, but only half of the distortion and does not apply to paths (unless double float rounding is a problem). But one can never know. Thats why i suggested to do this on a separate artboard. Anyway the transform has other advantages. Good trick though.

Comment: @ACEkin wasnt thet the first version you had. Again snap direction by holding shift rotates with view... So no precise snapping. So we are back to my first complaint.

Comment: @joojaa, if you press the R key, you will see the angle entry window on the toolbar. Try it, as I said, you can enter numeric angle values there.

Comment: Yes, i know that. But he wants to draw a precise line in x direction. BUT the rotation of view does rotate the snap direction of shift button so holding shift no longer draws a vertical line (relative to screen). Remeber, presumably he wants the line to be a PATH, the path will unfortunately rotate back, to wrong orientation.  So now i have to estimate the angle vertical line again.  Certainly easier than doing it in normal orientation but not precise (your prev answer is better in this regard). They might have changed the way it work in PS CC. But it wont work in CS 5 with rotate view.

Comment: I have nothing against this solution, if it would work. It would be more elegant if it would. But it does not work in my version of PS, unfortunately. Even though i can rotate the view precisely. Exactly the argument in my first comment. It does work for brushes though, just nut for paths and pen tool.

Comment: Stick to your way of doing it, you know it works for you. This one requires the graphics acceleration enabled, not everyone may have that.